# How to merge unallocated preceding partition using gparted or any other tool

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, gparted

I had windows 10 installed and I dual booted ubuntu 18.04 with it. Now I want to remove windows 10 and just keep ubuntu so i used gparted to remove windows 10 but now I can't resize `/dev/sda3` or `/dev/sda4` ? Need help..![image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: is that a dos partition table?

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize `/dev/sda3` or `/dev/sda4`, because they are currently mounted (the key symbol).
The easiest solution is to boot gparted from a [Live CD](https://gparted.org/download.php) or from a Linux Live USB stick and resize the partitions from there.